# Creating a class to switch Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've got an app with a Navigation Drawer which has a login screen as the main activity. I have a SharedPreference that gets set to true when the users log in.

In my class I would like to check the SharedPreference for the value and if it is true then go to another activity otherwise go to the login screen.

```
  public class loginCheck {
    Activity context;
    public void checkLogin(Activity context){
    this.context = context;

     //Get the preference from login
     SharedPreference loginchk = ....

   Intent intent;
   if(loginchk){

   intent = new intent(this, loginActivity)
   startActivity(intent);

     }else{

   intent = new intent(this, accountActivity)
   startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Currently I have a loginCheck Activity with the below but there is a lag when switching.

```
 SharedPreference loginchk = ....

   Intent intent;
   if(loginchk){

   intent = new intent(this, loginActivity)
   startActivity(intent);

     }else{

   intent = new intent(this, accountActivity)
   startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

What other options do I have to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lag'? Is there a delay before launching new activity? Please share the code how you use loginCheck class

Comment: Selecting the loginCheck Activity from the navigation drawer lags"Slow to go to the correct activity".. Once I hit the row in the Navigation Drawer it hits a Intent to the loginCheckActivity which has the above check.